# Выводит ошибку помогите, что делать?

Tags: c#

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex + count > this.length
>   Parameter name: count System.String.Remove (Int32 startIndex, Int32
>   count)

Comment: Ну вроде сообщение об ошибке вполне однозначно вам проблему описывает. Можете еще на MSDN ознакомиться когда это сообщение выдается: [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Скорее всего вы пытаетесь сделать Remove с параметрами, выхохдящими за пределы строки. Например, пытаетесь удалить 1000 символов из строки "Привет". Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте код - и вам помогут найти ошибку.